# How do I add more data to the same user without updating or creating a new row?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Let's say in the database I have the following table:

Table - workers

With the following fields

- name
- origin
- destination
- date
- worker_id (PK)(AI)

What I want to do here is have let's say the first user with more than 1 record on  `origin`,`destinations` and `date` filled out.

So essentially, say I have user "Mike" and I want to insert several `"origin"` and `"destination"` and `"date"` information without always repeating  his name on the table that is going to display the data.

What I need here is for a single `"worker_id"` (let's say worker_id is 1) to have more than 1 single information on each field.

I've tried the following query (only using the origin field for testing purposes):

`"INSERT INTO workers(origin) SELECT FROM workers WHERE worker_id ='$worker_id'";`

What I wanted to end up with would be something like:

`Worker ID - 1 Origin - Brazil`

`Worker ID - 1 Origin - Japan`

`Worker ID - 1 Origin - Australia`

If it's just my logical thinking that is wrong, then I'd highly appreciate if someone could point me in the right way. For one ID, have several information for a single field.

Comment: Another table that holds the "id" and the origin" and "destination" and "date", then use a join on "id" in your query.

Comment: Just remember never to put PHP variables directly in the SQL query. Always use prepared statements.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most easier solution would be [normalising the database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).
In your case that would mean following tables (I assumed the **origin** and **destination** is some sort of travel log data).

**user**

```
id
name
```

**travel_log**

```
id
worker_id
origin
destination
date
```

And then you would join them to get your desired (mentioned) data:

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.name, t.origin, t.destination, t.date 
FROM user u 
JOIN travel_log t ON u.id = t.worker_id
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you sir! You are a god!